# jquery ajax evaluate <script> tags on original page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a page with a `ul` that has the `li` generated within a `script` tag.  I'm using ajax to transfer this list to another page.  I would like for the ajax call to return the content generated by the `script` tags (and not the javascript contained within the `script` tag) because I do not have access to the relevant variables on the page receiving the content.  Is there a way to do this?

EDIT:
The content I want is the list on this page: http://comunidad.winguweb.org/?t=368658.

It is generated using the following code (NOTE: this code passes Liquid variables to Javascript.  These Liquid variables cannot be accessed on the receiving end of the ajax call.  The point of the ajax call is to generate this list and then pass it to a location that cannot generate it.  I may need to use something that is not ajax for this.):

```
<ul id='usuardest'>
  <li>testingbottom</li>
</ul>  
<script>
  var userarr = [];
  var len = 0;
  {% for topic in topics %}
    {% for question in topic.questions %}
      len = userarr.length;
      var femail = '{{ question.from_email | replace: "'","/'"}}';
      if (len == 0){
        userarr = [{fromemail: femail, helpful: 1, username: '{{ question.from_name | replace: "'","/'"}}'}]}
      else {
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          if (userarr[i].fromemail == femail) {
            userarr[i].helpful ++; }
          else if (i == (len - 1)) {
            userarr.push({fromemail: femail, helpful: 1, username: '{{ question.from_name | replace: "'","/'"}}'}); }
        }
      }
      {% for answer in question.answers %}
        len = userarr.length;
        var femail = '{{ answer.from_email | replace: "'","/'"}}';   
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
          if (userarr[i].fromemail == femail) {
            userarr[i].helpful ++; }
          else if (i == (len - 1)) {
            userarr.push({fromemail: femail, helpful: 1, username: '{{ answer.from_name | replace: "'","/'"}}'}); }
        }
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
  userarr.sort(function(productA, productB){
    return productB.helpful - productA.helpful
  });
  var udest = document.getElementById('usuardest');
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    udest.innerHTML = udest.innerHTML + "<li>" + userarr[i].username + userarr[i].helpful + "</li>";
  }
</script>
```

The ajax query I am using to get it is:

```
var debug;
$(function() {
  $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "http://comunidad.winguweb.org/?t=368658",
  dataType: "html",
  success: parseHTMLagain
  });
});
```

The parsing function I am using to incorporate the results of the query is:

```
function parseHTMLagain(html) {
  "use strict";
  $(html).filter('#usuardest').appendTo('#listadestac');
}
```

Comment: "I'm using ajax to transfer this list to another page"...what?? I'm really missing out on something here. Ajax goes from client to server on one page. If you're sending the user to a new page, with the list as a parameter, then there's no way to "return" anything. Either you need to rephrase your question so it's a bit clearer...or you're attempting something that's not actually possible. (for instance; I don't suppose there are multiple windows involved?)

Comment: I do not know if I understand your question but maybe're needing something like http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: The server doesn't know about the generated `li` so it CANT serve it to you on a different page. Your best chance is to use the same script and data, to generate the list on your other page

Comment: As I understand it, you need the rendered result inside of the `ul` tag. That means you can use [html getter](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `<iframe>` works...